# Mysql myisam insert SLOWER than innodb

Tags: mysql, performance, innodb, myisam, sql-insert

I have a mysql server with production database and a staging database. I am using innodb for the production tables, but I don't need the features for staging which just moves data around. So I decided to switch those tables to myisam expecting an increase in insert performance.

The results were horrible. It looked more like inserting into an innodb table without autocommit disabled. If I keep the table innodb and turn off autocommit during the insert I can get several thousand inserts per second. As soon as I change the table to myisam I'm getting maybe a couple dozen inserts per second.

I thought maybe it was because I'm getting the data via our legacy backend using SSIS but that doesn't appear to be the issue. Using SSIS and going from our production db to the staging db (mysql to mysql) I still see the same results... innodb(no autocommit) far out performs myisam.

This makes no sense to me. If nothing else, in my experience, myisam should at least be comparable, hopefully even better.

Is there anything obvious I am overlooking? I haven't included specifics in hopes that it is something in general I am missing.

**EDIT:**

This appears to be related to SSIS and the ODBC Destination component. I'm using an ODBC Source that has my select statement and the output goes to the ODBC Destination which is table on the same server, but a different DB. Since the DBs are on the same server I ran, in SqlYog, an INSERT using the same SELECT query as the ODBC Source and it finished in a couple seconds. I will see if I can find a solution.

Comment: I'd probably be checking the myisam specific buffers here. Assuming nothing has changed with indexes etc. and your table files are on the same storage as the ibdata file(s)?

Comment: Please see my edit. Before I figured it out I did up the key_buffer_size and bulk_insert_buffer_size to 256M with no success.

Comment: MyISAM is old engine.. InnoDB is build to be fast.. "write InnoDB delivered 4.6x higher throughput than MyISAM," and "Read en write InnoDB delivered 35x higher throughput than MyISAM" see http://www.oracle.com/partners/en/knowledge-zone/mysql-5-5-innodb-myisam-522945.pdf